# C# .NET 7.0 Failure to connect to Azure database for MySQL using SSL cert file authentication

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, azure

I am currently testing the connection string to an Azure database for MySQL. I can successfully connect to the database on MySQL Workbench.

This is the my Program.cs where I tried to input the connection string and test it. I am running MacOS and .NET 7.0.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Text;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Server = "AzureDatabaseName.mysql.database.azure.com",
            Port = 3306,
            Database = "DatabaseName",
            UserID = "AzureDBUsername",
            Password = "AzureDBPass",
            SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Required,
            CertificateFile = "/Users/user/Desktop/Coding/source/repos/CSTest/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem"

        };

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
            conn.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection closed.");
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added some packages to try and fix the problem, none have worked so far. Here is what my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.5">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="6.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Permissions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I run the program, this is the results:

```
/Users/user/Desktop/Coding/source/repos/CSTest/CSTest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'MySql.Data 6.8.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
/Users/user/Desktop/Coding/source/repos/CSTest/CSTest.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'MySql.Data 6.8.3' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
Connecting to MySQL...
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> Interop+AppleCrypto+SslException: bad protocol version
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/user/Desktop/Coding/source/repos/CSTest/Program.cs:line 26
Connection closed.
```

I have double checked the connection string information a few times, but could I just be dumb and that has to be the problem? For reference, the SSL certificate file path is the same as the one being used in the MySQL connection. Also am not sure if the program needs to be on .NET 7.0 and the warning should be looked into.

Comment: MySql.Data 6.8.3 is over seven years old; have you tried using v8.0.33 or an alternative library like MySqlConnector https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Bradley Grainger` for the comments.

The error message shows that the authentication failed due to a bad protocol version.

This is due to **incompatibility of the version of MySQL connector and the version of the .NET framework** you are using.

You need to update the MySQL connector to a version that is compatible or latest version matching to the `.NET framework version`.

Choose `Manage NuGet packages` from Visual studio and select the `latest version` and install it.

[image]

And check the `SSL certificate file` is in the correct format and that the path to the file is correct. Also use the full path to the certificate file instead of a relative path.

For further information in connecting to an `Azure database for MySQL` using `SSL cert file authentication`, check the [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-configure-ssl) and [MSDoc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-ssl-connection-security).